# How to display only not null columns in a fetched mysql row?

Tags: python, mysql, database, null

I have a table in mysql with 80 columns. Most of these columns have no value, null. In general, each row returns about 8 or 9 columns that are not null (Data has been inserted). I believe there is no way in mysql statement to return from a fetched row only the columns that are not null. My question is, as I am a beginner in Python, What's the best approach in that script to accomplish my goal ? Explained it better as bellow:

1. A mysql query fetched a row
2. The row has 8 not null columns
3. The row has 72 null columns
4. if first column is not null then display column name and column data
5. if second column is not null then display column name and column data
   6  if third column is not ........ and so on until the last column

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Which mysql Python library are you using?  If you fetch the row as a simple array, you can loop through them and print only the ones with a value.  The libraries all have a way to fetch the list of column names as an array as well.

Comment: mysql can filter the null value, use " where value is not null " hope this help a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output list must be definite - i.e. the amount of columns in it cannot be dynamic. You may decide, for example, that the output will contain 10 columns, and create according query.

Pattern:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN cnt > 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(total, CHAR(0), 1), CHAR(0), -1)
            END field1,
       CASE WHEN cnt > 1 
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(total, CHAR(0), 2), CHAR(0), -1)
            END field2,
       ..
       CASE WHEN cnt > 9
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(total, CHAR(0), 10), CHAR(0), -1)
            END field10,
       cnt
FROM ( SELECT id, 
              CONCAT_WS(CHAR(0), field1, field2, .. , field80) total,
              field1 IS NOT NULL + field2 IS NOT NULL + .. + field80 IS NOT NULL cnt
       FROM source_table ) AS compacted
```

The idea is simple - CONCAT_WS skips NULL values. CHAR(0) is used as delimiter because it is the most rare char in a value of any non-binary datatype.

If the amount of NOT NULL values is below 10 then the rest of output values will be NULL.

If the amount of NOT NULL values is above 10 then the rest of values won't be shown. This can be detected by `cnt` column value instead of 80 BIT columns.

But your values are `0` or `1` only so you may simplify the query till

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING(total FROM 1 FOR 1) field1,
       SUBSTRING(total FROM 2 FOR 1) field2,
       ...
       SUBSTRING(total FROM 10 FOR 1) field10,
       cnt
FROM ( SELECT id, 
              CONCAT_WS('', field1, field2, .. , field80) total,
              field1 IS NOT NULL + field2 IS NOT NULL + .. + field80 IS NOT NULL cnt
       FROM source_table ) AS compacted
```

The difference - this query wil return empty string, not NULL value, for excess columns. If you need NULLs then apply NULLIF() function.

---

But I strongly recommend you to normalize your data. Either use EAV pattern or at least 2 columns of SET datatype.